# Splitting LinkedList

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I had a question on the below function, which splits a LinkedList in to two equal sized lists. I understand how for the "slow" list, we iterate through the original list until "fast" is null (and at that time, "slow" will have gone through half the list). However, I am not understanding how "head" becomes only the first half of the list. I don't see anywhere in the code that modifies head directly. Apologies if this is a naive question -- new to LinkedLists!

```
function splitLL(head) {
        let prev = null;
        let slow = head;
        let fast = head;
        while(fast !== null && fast.next !== null) {
            prev = slow;
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        prev.next = null
        console.log("This is first half", head);
        console.log("This is second half", slow);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is passing around references to the object. When `prev.next = null` is run it is cutting off half of `head`. `prev` is a reference to the object in the linked list and editing `prev` edits `head`.

Here is an annotated source walking through the values as they change.

```
let ll = {
    id: 1,
    next: { id: 2, next: { id: 3, next: { id: 4, next: null } } }
};

function splitLL(head) {
    let prev = null;
    let slow = head; // <= slow is now a reference to node 1
    let fast = head; // <= fast is now a reference to node 1
    while (fast !== null && fast.next !== null) {
        prev = slow; // prev = node 1
                     // next loop prev = node 2
        slow = slow.next; // slow = node 2
                          // next loop slow = node 3
        fast = fast.next.next;  // fast = node 3
                                // next loop fast = node 4
    }
    // when fast is equal to node 4 the while loop ends

    prev.next = null; // this is now node 2, by setting this to null it edits head
    console.log("This is first half", head);
    console.log("This is second half", slow);
}
splitLL(ll);
```

Play around with javascript objects in the console. You'll notice that by assigning an object to two variables and editing one you can edit the original object.

Comment: Thank you for this! Did not realize that by editing prev, we were also editing head. Appreciate you breaking it down

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to modify head because the head of the original list is still the head of one of the shorter lists. For example if the original list was:

```
head -> node1 -> node2 -> node3 -> null
```

The broken up lists would now be

```
head  -> node1 -> null
node2 -> node3 -> null
```

The original head doesn't need to be modified. It's a little like cutting a rope in half. The start of of one of the halves is the original start of the whole rope.